# Is there a reasonable built-in implementation for "typing.NamedTuple.__eq__"?

Tags: python

It seems like there is such a built-in feature, but I can't find documentation about it.

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug 10 2022, 11:19:32) [GCC 12.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from typing import NamedTuple
>>> class Foo(NamedTuple):
...     bar: int
...     baz: str
...
>>> foobar1 = Foo(1, "bar")
>>> foobar2 = Foo(1, "bar")
>>> foobar3 = Foo(2, "bar")
>>> foobar1 == foobar2
True
>>> foobar1 == foobar3
False
```

Comment: It inherits from `tuple` and uses the `__eq__` of `tuple`. Refer to [Comparing Sequences and Other Types](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)

Comment: @MechanicPig: Thanks, that's good enough for me (even though I cannot even find a hint in the ```typing``` module docs about ```NamedTuple``` inheriting from ```tuple```.

Comment: The first line in the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) indicates that it is a typing version of [`collection.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), so you should learn about it first.

Comment: I stand corrected, you are completely right ...